# Explicitly ignoring NULL value but C behaves weird

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I am writing a program to check a certain word in a string. I use strtok to chop up the string and store it in an array. There is no problem with that.

The problem comes when I try to check the value of the wordArray at a certain index and say that if it is not NULL, save into a variable, and if it is NULL, do nothing. However, it is not ignoring NULL.

My code is below:

```
// This is a string to consider
char line[] = "I am here"; 
// Array of pointers to later hold pointers to each word
char *wordArray[MAX_LINE_LEN]; 

// Below is the chopping function, this is working well
// First chop up the first word, using the original string
wordArray[0] = strtok(line, " "); 
int i = 0;

// Then loop to chop up and save into wordArray
while(wordArray[i] != NULL){
    i++;
    wordArray[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
// Print out the words in wordArray
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  printf("Word at index %d in wordArray is: %s \n",j, wordArray[j]);
}

// This is a part I don't get

// First define a character array/pointer so that it's the same type with wordArray
char *word = "a word";
int i = 0;

// Check wordArray at a certain key, if not null, save the value into word variable
if (wordArray[i] != NULL) {
    word = wordArray[i];
}
printf("Word is: %s \n", word);
```

When i = 0:

```
Word is: I
```

When i = 2:

```
Word is: here
```

When i = 3 (at this point it's doing the right thing - ignore the if statement):

```
Word is: a word
```

When i >= 4:

```
Word is:
```

Nothing prints out. What exactly is its problem? How do I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to all the help! The problem is wordArray has not been initialized with NULL values. Here's what I add:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LINE_LEN; i++) {
   wordArray[i] = NULL;
}
```

This is an array of pointers so I used NULL, but for an array of characters it will probably prefer `wordArray[i] = '\0'` since `'\0'` is a null character array.

Comment: You may be invoking *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration. Please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Shouldn't you do `if (wordArray[key] != NULL) { word = wordArray[key]; }` instead?

Comment: @Pablo Right thanks for pointing that out! I meant to write word = wordArray[i] !

Comment: `wordArray[4]` (and above) is never initialized/assigned in your code to any meaningful value. It contains garbage. Yet you for some reason expect it to be null. Why do you expect it to be null? If you want your array elements to be null initially, declare it as `char *wordArray[MAX_LINE_LEN] = { 0 };`.

Comment: @AnT Thanks you were right!

Comment: @MikeCAT Yes that is true!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Array of pointers to later hold pointers to each word
char *wordArray[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

wordArray is not intially assigned with null.

```
// Then loop to chop up and save into wordArray
while(wordArray[i] != NULL){
    i++;
    wordArray[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

above loop will terminate when value of i reach to 4.so ,wordArray[4] is not  initialsed. since,wordArray coming from stack and you are not initializing its value can be anything.so ,below condition will not fail.

```
if (wordArray[i] != NULL) {
    word = wordArray[key];
}
```

you are lucky that you didnt get hard fault as for this case word is pointing to any random pointer you will get undefined behavior here.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was definitely the problem! I saw some similar mistakes in my program as well. I will definitely take notes of this. Thanks again!